# Docker: Internal Ports

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm new to docker and wondering why so many examples of docker-compose map ports from internal to external instead of just keeping them the same. For example, one postgres example I saw mapped 4612:5432.

Is there a reason people don't just keep it 5432:5432?

Comment: Doing this allows you to have multiple instances of postgres running on seperate ports. Useful if you are developing multiple applications simultaneously that both require a database.

Comment: @JackGore if you aren't developing multiple apps, is there any other reason to do this either in dev or prod? just making sure this isn't some security thing i wasn't aware of or something.

Comment: One other common occurrence you'll see is mapping http servers `80:8080` or `443:8080` where `:80` is conventionally http and `:443` is conventionally https but these are in the restricted (root) port range (<1024). Defaulting the containers to the higher ports shouldn't require them to be run as root (though they often still are).

Comment: Also, since you mentioned docker-compose, it's common to see ports exposed to the host machine but this is often unnecessary. For internal only services (e.g. a database being accessed by some web container), you need only specify the container's port for it to be accessible to other services. If you wish the service to be accessible from the host, then you need to specify the `[host-port]:[container-port]` mapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be different reasons not to map to same port on host: doing this allows to have multiple Postgres running on separate ports and tweak them in case for some reason you want different ports in DEV/PROD.

Answer (score 1):

For local dev env, except for port conflicting issues, there is no other reason. 
Unlike exposing ports to internet, there is no security reasons for container port mapping and exposing.